# Convert WIF to Witness PubKey Hash Address in Go

Tags: address, p2wpkh

How can WIF be easily converted to WitnessPubKeyHash in Go?

We need to get the public key from WIF and than calculate witness program as `ripemd160(sha256(compressed_pub_key))`.

But is there a function in `btcutil` to convert the public key to `witnessProg` required by [NewAddressWitnessPubKeyHash](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcutil/blob/master/address.go#L520) function:

```
func NewAddressWitnessPubKeyHash(witnessProg []byte, net *chaincfg.Params) (*AddressWitnessPubKeyHash, error)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 cases where the version byte in the witness program is either 0 or 1.
If the version byte is 0, you need a 20-byte HASH160 of the public key. Reference [wiki](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#witness-program).

```
witnessProg := btcutil.Hash160(w.SerializePubKey())
p2wpkh, err := btcutil.NewAddressWitnessPubKeyHash(witnessProg, chainParams)
```

But I am not really sure about the case where version byte is 1.

Edit: previous implementation was probably wrong, fixed after some more research.